# Searching first and last occurrence of multiple patterns

Tags: string, grep, pattern-matching

I was wondering if someone can help me simplifying shell command into one or two lines, can we use awk or sed for simplifying the execution, better performance during execution is much appriciated

Input file

```
    PATTERN1 xxx
    PATTERN2 xxx
    PATTERN3 xxx
    PATTERN1 yyy
    PATTERN2 yyy
    PATTERN3 yyy
    PATTERN1 zzz
    PATTERN2 zzz
    PATTERN3 zzz
```

My script:

```
    echo "First occurance..."
    grep -m1 "PATTERN1" $fileName
    grep -m1 "PATTERN2" $fileName
    grep -m1 "PATTERN3" $fileName

    echo "Last occurance..."
    tac $fileName | grep -m1 "PATTERN1"
    tac $fileName | grep -m1 "PATTERN2"
    tac $fileName | grep -m1 "PATTERN3"
```

Output

```
    PATTERN1 xxx
    PATTERN2 xxx
    PATTERN3 xxx
    PATTERN1 zzz
    PATTERN2 zzz
    PATTERN3 zzz
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just two commands:

```
$ awk '/PATTERN[1-3]/ && !seen[$1]++' file
    PATTERN1 xxx
    PATTERN2 xxx
    PATTERN3 xxx

$ tac file | awk '/PATTERN[1-3]/ && !seen[$1]++'
    PATTERN3 zzz
    PATTERN2 zzz
    PATTERN1 zzz
```

This prints a match the first time it is seen.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using `grep`, you could use `xargs`.

Let's put patterns in a variable

```
patterns=`echo "PATTERN"{1..3} | tr ' ' '\n'`
# or
patterns="PATTERN1\nPATTERN1\nPATTERN3"
```

So now we can do something like this:

```
echo -e "$patterns" | xargs -l sh -c 'cat '$inputFile' | grep -m1 "$0"'
echo -e "$patterns" | xargs -l sh -c 'tac '$inputFile' | grep -m1 "$0"'
```